# How to make Vertical Line with blured colour in Top and Bottom Line with CSS

Tags: html, css, graphics, line, blur

as you know from the title, i want to make a line like this with css like this.

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You need to show what you've tried to do first before asking a question like this. And what you're talking about isn't blurring, it's a gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, this is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .verticalLine{
      height: 300px; /* Length of your line */
      border-left: 2px solid transparent;
      filter: blur(1px); /* Amount of bluryness */
      border-image: linear-gradient(white, black, white) 10 stretch;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="verticalLine"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Tacchino Robot's answer is almost perfect, add some blur and you have exactly what was requested.

If you're happy with this solution, please mark this as an answer (tick), so others know it's solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way:

```css
.line {
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(white,black,white) 10 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
</div>
```

You have to play with colors but the result is kinda the same.